# How to turn paths to files into path to directories

Tags: php

Example, instead of

> facebook.com/mywall.php

you use

> facebook.com/mywall

Comment: There are no query strings in this question. Perhaps you could clarify it?

Comment: I don't see any [query strings](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Query_string) in your example. Are you looking for some kind of URL rewriting or redirecting?

Comment: I changed the question, I did not mean query strings, lol

Comment: See [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2358178/running-php-without-extension-without-using-mod-rewrite). You can either use mod_rewrite or turn on MultiViews.

Comment: Maybe it'd easier if you posted your current source code, its output, what you would _like_ its output to be, and where you're stuck in reaching your goal.

Answer (score 3):

Apache mod rewrite: http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html

You use `.htaccess` to rewrite the rules for your urls and how they are handled.