# http POST method for web server

Tags: post, file-upload, curl, http-headers, http-post

I'm looking at HTTP POST method to create a web page.
I'm a tad unfamiliar with it, and was looking for some explanation on how this works.

I'm simply wanting to use their seemingly simplistic page for my own server needs.
My question is this, how does this curl link really work?

```
curl --data-binary @audio2.flac --header 'Content-type: audio/x-flac; rate=16000' 'https://www.google.com/speech-api/v1/recognize?xjerr=1&client=chromium&pfilter=0&maxresults=1&lang="en-US"'
```

So I got it to work by using curl, by sending a flac file as you can see, and it responds with 
this JSon stuff

```
{"status":0,"id":"3b7853241a0dded048f84744cc1ab896-1","hypotheses":[{"utterance":"ice cream","confidence":0.88215643}]}
```

Please correct me if I'm wrong:
So I believe this is a post method as it has the ? mark with it to send the name value pair.
I have no idea how they got the link https://www.google.com/speech-api/v1/recognize
to only accept POST requests without having a script name like this at the end

```
https://www.google.com/speech-api/v1/recognize/scriptName.pl
```

How do I write something to accept a post request at that given page without a .pl or .py extension?  How can I put it in a certain directory on the server.

In addition for my purposes can I also send a file back to them once I process / zip?
Any ideas on how to do that?

Thanks so much for your time and generous help!

Comment: arguments passed via ? and & in the URI are handled as GET

Comment: I was thinking that.  This is what I found in the man page of curl though.         --data-binary <data> (HTTP)  This  posts data exactly as specified with no extra processing whatsoever.  If you start the data with the letter @, the rest  should  be  a filename.   Data  is  posted in a similar manner as --data-ascii does, except that newlines are  preserved  and conversions are never done.

Comment: Also this is a response to get.  cam@Firetree:~$ curl https://www.google.com/speech-api/v1/recognize
<HTML>
<HEAD>
<TITLE>HTTP method GET is not supported by this URL</TITLE>
</HEAD>
<BODY BGCOLOR="#FFFFFF" TEXT="#000000">
<H1>HTTP method GET is not supported by this URL</H1>
<H2>Error 405</H2>
</BODY>
</HTML>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that if you use --data/--data-binary/--form that the request is POSTed.

I first totally misunderstood your question and though you wanted to know how to use the interface, but you got that working.

The serverside can be achieved by multiple means, totally depending on the infrastructure and software used.

With the Webserver apache for example, you could use [Rewrite](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/rewrite/intro.html) or something in a [HtAccess](http://www.php.net/manual/en/security.hiding.php) file to obfuscate/change the requested file. So looking at the extension (or the absence of it) is not helpful.

Please also see various options mentioned here

[Running PHP without extension without using mod_rewrite?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2358178/running-php-without-extension-without-using-mod-rewrite)

or

[ForceType/htaccess file extension question - extensionless files?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4740614/forcetype-htaccess-file-extension-question-extensionless-files)

to see how you could achieve the same.

Only accepting POST data is then again dependant on the programming/scripting technique you employ at your server side, PHP e.g. distinguishes between multiple [superglobals](http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.superglobals.php) like [$_GET](http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.get.php) and [$_POST](http://www.php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.post.php).