# how to remove the .php extension from url, for a file named same like a folder

Tags: php, .htaccess

I used this code

```
## remove the php extention
RewriteEngine on 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.php -f 
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1.php
```

This works for some files the e.g. `example.com/contact`, but doesn't work when I have a `.php` file that is also a directory. For example, in the root folder:

```
science.php 
science - folder
```

The articles are in categories e.g. `http://example.com/science/themost-blabla.php` - this works, the `.php` extionsion doesn't appear in the URL.

So I want to know if is any possible to hide the `.php` extension to `science.php` because when I type `example.com/science` ... it redirects me to the content of the science folder....

Index of `/science` directory:

- `afla-care-a-fost-primul-meci-televizat-de-fotbal-din-lume-1937-arsenal.php`
- `cazinoul-din-constanta.php cele-7-minuni-ale-lumii.php`
- `descoperire-colosala-a-epavei-navei-spaniole-san-jose-ce-avea-la-bord-o-avere-impresionanta.php`
- `imagini/ mitologia-greaca.php poenaru.php`
- `top-10-cele-mai-importante-inventii-romanesti-din-istorie.php`
- `top-5-enigme-ale-lumii.php turnul-eiffel.php`

So, can I do something to hide the extension to this page? Or do I need to change the name of the file - to not be the some as the folder?

Comment: There's this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2358178/running-php-without-extension-without-using-mod-rewrite

Comment: You cannot rewrite the url to a file if there is a folder named the same as a file. The ressource needs to be uniquely identifiable and thats not the case anymore if you remove the extension.

Comment: What you can do is to move the file into the science folder and name it index.php, this solution wouldn't require url rewriting too.

Comment: @CharlotteDunois "You cannot rewrite the url to a file if there is a folder named the same as a file." - Well, you can. The "folder" includes a trailing slash, whereas the file does not. However, you need to set `DirectorySlash Off` in order to avoid conflict.

Comment: @w3dk Doing that will downgrade your searchenginerank since both pages with and without trailing slashes should be the same content (better to make a 301 redirecting from one to another to avoid getting double results). It's bad practice to deliver two different results with and without trailing slashes and will only bring up confuses. Also it shows you are not thinking much as a developer if you thinking this is the solution to your "problem".

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^([^\.]+)$ $1.php [NC,L]
```

Comment: Hey,  I gone through your answer then I  understood properly. It's my mistake, thanks for the correction....

Comment: Providing the OP doesn't need to access the bare directory (eg. `science/`) and is always accessing files, then if you include the `DirectorySlash Off` directive (to prevent mod_dir from appending a slash) then this solution does go someway to solving the problem.

Answer (score 0):

One of the "problems" is that mod_dir will try to "fix" the URL when accessing a directory by appending a slash to the end of the URL. However, this can be disabled.

```
# Prevent mod_dir from automatically appending slashes to directories
DirectorySlash Off

# Disable directory listings
# In cases where there is a directory with no similar .php file and no DirectoryIndex
Options -Indexes

# If a PHP file exists for the requested URL then rewrite to this
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.php -f 
RewriteRule (.*) $1.php [L]
```

If required, bare directories (or rather, the `DirectoryIndex`) can be accessed by explicitly appending a slash to the URL. eg. `example.com/science/`. However, this is presumably unnecessary (and probably best avoided to avoid user confusion) since I assume `example.com/science` (no trailing slash, ie. `science.php`) returns your "science" *category* content. Without a `DirectoryIndex` document, `example.com/science/` will simply return a 403 Forbidden. Alternatively you could explicitly remove trailing slashes from such URLs with an external redirect.